# Vector scalar product and Fourier transform in the hyperbolic plane?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, fourier-transform, hyperbolic-geometry

I study a set of points $r_j$ in the hyperbolic plane, let's say in the upper half plane $\{ z\in\mathbb{C} | \Im(z)>0\}$, and I try to define a [structure factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_factor) in the same spirit as we would define it in crystallography (the Fourier transform of a forest of Dirac deltas):
$$S(\mathbf{q})=\sum_{j,k} e^{i \mathbf{q\cdot (r_j-r_k)}}$$

I would like to know what is the scalar product in the case of [vectors of the hyperbolic plane](http://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/ereyes/seminarpaper.pdf) so that it would make sense in the complex exponential to define this kind of Fourier transform. Otherwise, I would be interested in any other approach to define the Fourier transform in the hyperbolic geometry.

Here is an attempt based of the analogy with the Euclidian geometry: 
Since angles are the same in the Euclidian plane and in the upper half plane, we could use **u.v=|u||v|** cos(**u^v**)

where  **u**$=(u_1,u_2)$ is a hyperbolic segment in the upper half plane,

**|u|** is the hyperbolic distance $d(u_1,u_2)$

and **u^v** is the angle between the [directions](http://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/ereyes/seminarpaper.pdf) of **u** and **v**.

The value of **u^v** remains however unknown to me.